# How to do .asf streaming file integration in android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, asf

I want to integrate .asf file video stream in android application. How to do it. I have searched for it but didnot find any helpful code. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: whats your stream server platform?which streaming technic is better for you?do you know HLS? or do you know ffmpeg?

Comment: I don't have any streaming server, I have a video with .asf extension in server location. How that will play in My App, I am able to play .mp4 from same server location. like localhost:8080/videos/abc.mp4 and localhost:8080/videos/xyz.asf

Comment: i think that if you can play mp4, change format of video to mp4 in fly with ffmpeg. it very simple and useful.

Comment: actually some of videos may have 80GB, so this not possible to convert and store the file.

Comment: i say you can change format on fly...it mean that you dont need to store any file on your server ...but the better way to your problem is HLS, do you know HLS?